# Can a stochastic process be decomposed as follows?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, autoregressive

So for instance an AR(1) process

\begin{equation}
x_t=\rho x_{t-1}+u_t
\end{equation}

where, say, $u_t\sim IID(0,1)$ for $t\in \mathbb{N}$, can be expressed using backward iteration as follows:

\begin{equation}
x_t=\rho^{t}x_0 +\sum\limits_{i=0}^{t-1}\rho^iu_{t-i}
\end{equation}
where $x_0$ is fixed. However, this is expressed as a model. Are there any model-free representation (or rather decomposition) of a stochastic process, such that it also includes the initial fixed value $x_0$?

Comment: Could you please explain to us what you mean by a "model"?  What would constitute a "model-free" representation?

Comment: Firstly, I must apologise, as I am struggling to word this question properly. I have a vague idea in my head and hoping for someone to pick up my intention and provide a suggestion. Well, for instance, the AR(p) process is an additive model and is a linear function of all last p lags (and perhaps a constant). I suppose "model-free" is not the best way to put it, I am trying to express a more generalised expansion of a discrete-time stochastic process.

Comment: It's completely unclear, though, what you are looking for.  Is there perhaps some non-technical way in which you could characterize your question?

Comment: I am considering a predictive regression of the form $y_t=\beta x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$. In the literature surrounding predictive regressions (mostly in the area of financial econometrics), it is generally assumed that $x_t$ follows and AR(1) or AR(p) process. I was hoping to have a more generalized expression for the $x_t$ as opposed to using the AR(1) or AR(p) models constantly considered in the literature.

Comment: Hi: There's the standard Y_t = level_t + trend_t + seasonal_t + noise_t decomposition which is additive. . But I don't know if that's what you;re looking for.  There's also a multiplicative version. Any decent intro time series book should discuss these in more detail.

Comment: I didn't read carefully but this might be useful. https://machinelearningmastery.com/decompose-time-series-data-trend-seasonality/